# While merging two or more objects, Is there any way to throw error on typescript if there is duplicate key present in any of those objects?

Tags: typescript, object

Suppose there is two object:

*obj A*

```
const A = {
  resetPassword: "/supplier/auth/reset-password",
  login: "/supplier/auth/login",
};
```

*obj B*

```
const B = {
  selfInitiate: "/supplier/actions/request",
  getEmpanelmentReport: "/supplier/empanelment/report",
  getFormData: "/supplier/empanelment/form/",
  formSubmit: "/supplier/empanelment/submit/",
  login: "duplicate login"
};
```

Now I want to merge these two objects in a single one, lets say its **object C**, where every key is read-only.

```
type SUPPLIER_ROUTE = {
  readonly selfInitiate: string;
  readonly getEmpanelmentReport: string;
  readonly getFormData: string;
  readonly formSubmit: string;
  readonly resetPassword: string;
  readonly login: string;
};

const C: SUPPLIER_ROUTE = {
  ...auth,
  ...empanelment
};
```

But here I want to throw error, cause there is a duplicate key `login` in both objects.
Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to detect any keys that are present in both objects. Here's one approach using a helper type to detect *duplicate* keys.

```
type Duplicates<T, U> = [
  {
    [K in keyof T & keyof U]: K extends keyof T
      ? K extends keyof U
        ? K
        : never
      : never;
  }[keyof T & keyof U],
] extends [never]
  ? T & U
  : never;
```

Using a [Mapped Type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#handbook-content) we check if a key (`K`) is a `keyof` both objects (`keyof T & keyof U`). If yes, we keep `K` in the mapped type and later [Index Access](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html#handbook-content) it to get a [Union Type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of all duplicate keys. Finally, we look whether there are duplicates: If `[duplicate keys union] extends [never]` there are none since `never` basically represents an empty union. We end up with `T & U` in that case otherwise with `never` to make any assignment illegal and produce a type error.

```
const auth = {
  resetPassword: "/supplier/auth/reset-password",
  login: "/supplier/auth/login",
};

const empanelment = {
  selfInitiate: "/supplier/actions/request",
  getEmpanelmentReport: "/supplier/empanelment/report",
  getFormData: "/supplier/empanelment/form/",
  formSubmit: "/supplier/empanelment/submit/",
  login: "duplicate login",
};

type SUPPLIER_ROUTE = {
  readonly selfInitiate: string;
  readonly getEmpanelmentReport: string;
  readonly getFormData: string;
  readonly formSubmit: string;
  readonly resetPassword: string;
  readonly login: string;
};

const C: Duplicates<typeof auth, typeof empanelment> = {
//    ~ Type '{ selfInitiate: string; getEmpanelmentReport: string; ... }' is not assignable to type 'never'.
  ...auth,
  ...empanelment,
} satisfies SUPPLIER_ROUTE;
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhgVygCxgXhgbwFAxgJwFMJCoAFOCCAdxHwBMAuGAIgHoIEAHLgGwEtC+NohRsiJKAFoulGnXosANLhi8QAc35hm7TjwFCRSZG3Vawy7AF8A3NmyhIsQgFtZYQr1eEwsDDh4JLwAZgCSYPxQ-HBQhLoc3HyCwnDA0eAQ4oQAjgjEUFZ4GqQAou5wnt6+UABKhFx0UAn6yUZuHl4+ftmN+IUqxaQAYnSuACKxcC1JhsIdlV01bCFjbEUwq-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)